# Mouseout background animation - CSS

Tags: html, css, mouseout, animated

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTh3A/8/) (html+css) you can see that if you mouseover the "link" both, `font` and `background`, slowly rea-animates but if you mouseout *ONLY* the font re-animates again. The `background` just fast blink back to

```
   a {background:}
```

How do I force the background to animate even on mouseout?

Comment: You actually have forced mouseout in your `#dolu a:hover` with `transition: background-color 5s;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had your transition for the background only on the hover. That means that if the user isn't hovering the transition isn't executed. By giving `#dolu a` `transition: 5s` instead of `transition: color 5s` it is fixed.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTh3A/9/)

Full CSS:

```
body {background: red; }

#dolu {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 5px; text-align: 
        center; width: 100%; 
}

#dolu a:hover {
    color: white; 
    background: rgb(31, 31, 31); 

} 
#dolu a {
    color: black; 
    background: white; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    font-variant: normal; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10 20 6 20; 
    transition: 5s; 
}
```

Comment: If this helped you please mark this answer as correct so others can also see ;)

Comment: Yes, it helped alot! I will as soon as I can do so.