# BG SWAPPING! How to swap to a different background image on mouseout for each rotating image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, mouseevent

So thanks to the help of the genius [stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507325/stark) I was able to successfully create a working array of images that cycle on hover. I decided to stick with images since it was easier to use rather than text. I just have one more question regarding this code. I'm trying to make each of these images have a corresponding background behind them, so when the user's mouse leaves the corresponding image, the background also changes. Here's the code so far:

JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/XavierTheGreat/s16yz34o/7/

CSS

```
<style>


   .hs-wrapper{
    width: 1015px;
    height: 408px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  background:url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/colorful-triangles-background_yB0qTG6.jpg");
}
.hs-wrapper img{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -moz-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -o-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -ms-animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    animation: showMe 0.8s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(1){
    z-index: 9;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    z-index: 8;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    z-index: 7;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    z-index: 6;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(5){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    z-index: 5;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(6){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    z-index: 4;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(7){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -ms-nimation-delay: 0.6s;
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    z-index: 3;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(8){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.hs-wrapper:hover img{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    -ms-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
.hs-overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.hs-overlay span{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 293px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 38px;
    border-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.hs-wrapper:hover .hs-overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}

@keyframes showMe {
    0% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    12.5% { visibility: visible; z-index: 100; }
    25% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
    100% { visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; }
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<section>
                <div class="hs-wrapper">
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1545/24610044154_20e82d4a01_o.jpg" alt="image01"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1677/25122429402_4983eefbd0_o.jpg" alt="image02"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1542/25240704165_73c03f1eff_o.jpg" alt="image03"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1447/24945094160_3c865f817b_o.jpg" alt="image04"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1545/24610044154_20e82d4a01_o.jpg" alt="image05"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1677/24610044594_f68cdd605c_o.jpg" alt="image06"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1693/24613897373_787d53a216_o.jpg" alt="image07"/>
                    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1478/25147517251_68206c1e74_o.jpg" alt="image08"/>

                </div>
            </section>
```

So would this be possible to do or am I overreaching in the limits of CSS and HTML? The only thing I can think of is using a mouseout event and the closest example i seen was made by this person:

[Mouseout background animation - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135898/mouseout-background-animation-css)

However I have no clue how that would work with my code. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want to changes your images bg ? You could change the DOM element BG but according to the fiddle, the images occupy all the space, the background wouldnt show.

Comment: Ahh great question, sorry about the confusion. I want to change the background behind the img tags if that makes sense, not the image tags themselves. I've updated the JSFiddle to reflect that. You should now see a green geometric BG behind all of these images, this is what I want to swap each time the user mousesout of the rotating images.

https://jsfiddle.net/XavierTheGreat/s16yz34o/7/

essentially there would be 8 of these bg's but only the corresponding BG is shown for each of the 8 images.

Comment: Anyone? Anyone at all?